# VBA to link Excel spreadsheets to Access

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a code in VBA in Access 2010 to link excel sheets and put them into tables in access. I keep getting an invalid outside of procedure at the `strFile = Dir(StrPath &"*.xls")` It keeps telling the the `strPath is invalid outside procedure`

Please help.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

'code will link to excel and pull site survey files into access tables

'Setting the path for the directory

Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\cparson\Documents\Survey_Eqpm\SiteSurveyData.xlsx"

'FileName
Dim strFile As String
'Array
Dim strFileList() As String
'File Number
Dim intFile As Integer

'Looping through the folder and building the file list
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
While strFile <> ""
    'adding files to the list
    intFile = intFile + 1
    ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
    strFileList(intFile) = strFile
    strFile = Dir()
Wend
'checking to see if files where found
If intFile = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Files Found"
    Exit Sub
End If
'going through the files and linking them to access
For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, , _
    strFileList(intFile), strPath & strFileList(intFile), True, "A5:J17"
Next
MsgBox UBound(strFileList) & "Files were linked"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an `End Sub` but no procedure name?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\cparson\Documents\Survey_Eqpm\SiteSurveyData.xlsx"

Dim strFile As String
Dim strFileList() As String
Dim intFile As Integer

Sub Sample() '<~~ You are missing this...
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")

    '~~> Rest of your code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it in a google search and realized that you already have the `.xlsx` extension in the `strPath` variable, but you add it to the string variable, `strFile`, also.

```
Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\cparson\Documents\Survey_Eqpm\SiteSurveyData.xlsx"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
```

I might be wrong, but just wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try too ADO, it's a easy way in my opnion

```
YourConnObj.execute "SELECT * INTO  YourTableName from [Excel 14.0;DATABASE=c:\temp\data copy.xlsx].[Sheet1]"
```